# What does ' ~' mean in sql cli prompt and how do I escape from it?

Tags: sql-server, command-line-interface, tilde

I was playing around in the SQL command line and I accidentally entered a command incorrectly.  Upon doing that the prompt changed from the expected '>' to '~' and I cant enter any new commands or make the tilde character go away

What does this mean and how do I escape from it?

My attempts below:

```
   select serverproperty'''sdf('''')
4~ go
5~ ;
6~ go
7~ undo
8~ stop
9~ quit
10~ quit
11~
12~
13~
14~
15~ quit
16~ stop
17~ go
18~ :EXIT\
19~ :EXIT
20~ exit
21~ EXIT
22~ EXIT
23~ GO
24~ Q
25~ exit()
26~ :Exit()
27~ :EXIT()
28~ GO
29~ select serverproperty('edition')
30~ go
31~ select serverproperty('edition')
32~ go
33~ ;
34~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're inside a single quote string. You started your string off with `'''` which opens the string, and then has an escaped single quote in it. Then you kept expanding said string. Then you never had a single quote (`'`) again so you never excited the literal string.

This animated gif might help explain further as well (this is `sqlcmd` but `mssql-cli` operates the same way):

[image]

First you have the statement below:

```
1> SELECT 1 AS one,
2>        2 AS two;
3> --Single command, with 2 lines, no quoted string
4> GO
```

This doesn't have a tilde (`~`) character as you aren't inside a string literal.

Then you have the second statement:

```
1> SELECT 'Line 1
2~ Line 2
3~ Line 3' AS String;
4> --Single command, 3 lines, 1 string
5> GO
```

This has tildes on lines 2 and 3 as they are within a literal string.

Comment: Huh... I envisioned you were faster on the keyboard.  :)   +1 especially for the visual.

Comment: Want me to try again and go faster this time @JohnCappelletti ? ;)

Comment: @Larnu, if I were typing the demo, we would still be waiting for the answer :-)

Comment: WOW!  Thanks for the quick reply and the straightforward answer.
Much appreciated! -OP